# Jquery droppable get draggable id

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

I want to get dragged id when i dropped to the certain div

```
  Drag  <ul id="demo" > 
         <li id="1" ></li>
         <li id="2" ></li>
        <li id="3" ></li>
        </ul>

         <div class="drop"> drop here!! </div>
```

JQUERY

```
  $(".drop").droppable({ 
                drop: function(event, ui) {

      // i need to get dragged id (note:able to  drag multiple ids)

        1,2,3..     

            }       
            });
```

Please help me out!! Thnks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As they says in jQuery UI [dropable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) doc

> All callbacks receive two arguments: The original browser event and a
>   prepared ui object, view below for a documentation of this object (if 
>   you name your second argument 'ui'):
>
> ui.draggable - current draggable element, a jQuery object.
>   ui.helper - current draggable helper, a jQuery object
>   ui.position - current position of the draggable helper { top: , left: }
>   ui.offset - current absolute position of the draggable helper { top: , left: }

`ui.draggable` is the element being dropped as a `jQuery object`.

So You can get the ID using `ui.draggable.prop('id')`

Comment: I tried   $(".drop").droppable({ 
            drop: function(event, ui) {
          var id=ui.draggable.prop('id');
  alert(id);
 }   }); but i am not getting any value. Please help me out i am dragging multiple ids

Answer (score 10):

You can use `ui.draggable` to address draggable element.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9RBJG/

Comment: Thanks!! But when i drop multiple items i need to all the ids which i have dropped. Something like 1,2,3

Comment: Please help me in getting multiple id. I dragging multiple ids.

Answer (score 0):

you can append the dropped nodes to a div, through the div you can get all the dropped ids. like below

```
$(".drop").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var id= ui.draggable.attr("id");
        $("#dropped-divs").append(id); 
    }
```